# AbsoluteOptions prints error messages in V10

Tags: plotting, bugs, options

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

I am trying to use AbsoluteOptions in V10 but I am getting the Out with some errors as see in this picture:

[image]

does anyone have same issue?

Comment: Same issue in Linux version.

Comment: Yes. I get it too. Windows 7.

Comment: I can confirm it on win 8.1.

Comment: Reproduced on Mac.  Report it to support!

Comment: Reproduced on the Wolfram Programming Cloud.

Comment: This is in some sense a more minimal example: `Graphics[Disk[], {Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}}] // AbsoluteOptions`.

Comment: @RunnyKine, How to report to Wolfram Programming Cloud?

Comment: You just have to report it once to Wolfram Research, the programming cloud is using the same engine as *Mathematica*.

Comment: I have reported this issue in the product feedback here: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/ ,is that correct?

Comment: @Algohi Usually somebody mails support@wolfram.com, but I filling out the email form on that site accomplishes about the same thing.

Comment: Errors still present in 10.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in 10.0.2. On windows 7, 64 bit:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is not really fixed, try `Plot[ Sin[x], {x,0,4}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]//AbsoluteOptions` and see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-bugs-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10)

Comment: @gwr I see. I was only using the example provided. For the example given, it did not give an error. There is a new post today on AbsoluteOptions problems also. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10  so it seems there is more issue still with this. May be you can post your example as separate question? This will make it easier to track it on its own?

Comment: I believe that Mr.Wizard might reformulate his question and then that should be the more general instance maybe?