# Forcing Ticks on Lower Left Corner of Plot

Tags: plotting, visualization, ticks

I have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

I need to have it labeled so that **14** appears in the lower left (I know it's obvious but that's what the publication I'm working with wants). That makes the origin of the graph clearer.

Is it possible to force '14' to appear in the lower left corner, and then keep the rest of the graph as is? I've been playing around with `Ticks` (a la adding the `Ticks->{{0.05,14},{0.10,14}}` flag manually, which seems to break as well.

Here's my code:

```
le={{14., 0.195652}, {15., 0.108434}, {16., 0.115108}, {17., 
  0.119565}, {18., 0.149091}, {19., 0.148855}, {20., 0.163498}, {21., 
  0.155303}, {22., 0.20922}, {23., 0.145522}, {24., 0.16129}, {25., 
  0.146617}, {26., 0.180812}, {27., 0.177536}, {28., 0.163636}, {29., 
  0.170455}, {30., 0.161172}, {31., 0.183099}, {32., 0.180272}, {33., 
  0.125}, {34., 0.126246}, {35., 0.0885246}, {36., 0.0771704}, {37., 
  0.0766773}, {38., 0.0711974}, {39., 0.0730897}, {40., 0.09}}

ListPlot[le, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> 0.3, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Apologizes if I'm missing something crushingly obvious.

Again, ideally the graph would look the same with the addition of '14' under the first datapoint in the lower left corner of the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Join[{{14, 14}}, Table[If[Mod[k, 5] == 0, {k, k}, {k, ""}], {k, 15, 40}]]
```

> ```
> {{14, 14}, {15, 15}, {16, ""}, {17, ""}, {18, ""}, {19, ""}, {20, 20}, {21, ""}, {22, ""}, {23, ""}, {24, ""}, {25, 25}, {26, ""}, {27, ""}, {28, ""}, {29, ""}, {30, 30}, {31, ""}, {32, ""}, {33, ""}, {34, ""}, {35, 35}, {36, ""}, {37, ""}, {38, ""}, {39, ""}, {40, 40}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[le
 , PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"
 , Joined -> True
 , Filling -> Bottom
 , AspectRatio -> 0.3
 , PlotRange -> {{13, All}, All}
 , AxesLabel -> Automatic
 , Ticks -> {
  Join[{{14, 14}}, Table[If[Mod[k, 5] == 0, {k, k}, {k, ""}], {k, 15, 40}]],
  Automatic
  }
 ]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

@kguler gave other solutions in a recent [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65189/how-to-add-special-ticks).

In particular there is an elegant one using the function `AbsoluteOptions`.

However it won't work for you in version 10 as `AbsoluteOptions` has been [reported broken](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54431/absoluteoptions-prints-error-messages-in-v10).

So, for Mathematica versions < 10 :

(`PlotTheme` option was introduced in v.10 but the "Monochrome" effect can be reproduced with `PlotMarkers, PlotStyle, FillingAxis`)

```
g = ListPlot[le, Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> 0.3,
 PlotRange -> {{13.5, Automatic}, Automatic}, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8]];
```

then

```
Show[g, Ticks -> {Join[First[Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[g]], {{14, 14.}}], Automatic}]
```

[image]