# Font style in Mathematica and .tex file

Tags: fonts, latex, mathematica-online

I am using Mathematica 8.
I want to label the axes of figure in "Times" font.

```
Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"z", "a(z)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]]
```

And the plot is 
[image]

However in Miktex, when I am using FontStyle, Times then z is different. So I want to replace  [image] 
by
[image]

the second one is the default z appearing pdf generarted from .tex file in math mode.
So what extra information should be given to Mathematica, besides "Times".

Comment: The second Z is Times Italic. To get that in Mathematica add the option `FontSlant-> Italic` to your Plot function call.

Comment: did not resolve the problem for me in Mathematica 8

Comment: You mean you did not get the italic version of the font?

Comment: @ Sjoerd Now its been resolved. I made a mistake previously as i added    FontSlant-> Italic in Label style. So that it italicized all the tikz labels also. Moreover, the required font was not visible in Mathematica 8.0, but when I saved it in .eps format and seen in the .pdf generated through Miktex it was visible. Thank you

Comment: If you can wait a couple of days, [I'll have an answer for this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hDGEh.png).  It's an accident that I'm doing this at the same time when you asked the question.  I didn't even see your question until now.

Comment: My approach is to use a non-$\LaTeX$ (installed system-wide) font in the `.tex` source and pick the same font in *Mathematica*. You can do the `tex` part either using `pdflatex` with suitable packages, or `xetex`, `luatex`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can match formatting between Mathematica figures and LaTeX using a small package I just wrote for using LaTeX-snippets in Mathematica: [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).

Here's an example:

```
<<MaTeX`

Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> BlackFrame,
 FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 20/12] &) /@ {"z", "a(z) = \\sin z"},
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 20}]
```

Additionally, I used the [Latin Modern](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) font for tick labels to fully match the "*LaTeX look*", and set the frame to be black instead of gray.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you prefer the Times font, we can do that too:

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}", "\\usepackage{txfonts}"}];

Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> BlackFrame, 
 FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 20/12] &) /@ {"z", "a(z) = \\sin z"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Today I also wanted to ask a similar question, but just when I had almost given up hope that a nice, clean solution would exist, I came across your answer and your easy-to-use package "MaTeX." Many thanks for developing such a convenient package (and for clearly documenting the steps needed to make it work)!

Comment: @TMM I'm glad you find it useful.  Feel free to email me if you have any comments or suggestions.

Comment: Actually there's one question I had, which may also be useful to readers of this website: is it possible to automate the MaTeXing further? i.e. Write something like MaTeX[Plot[x, {x,0,1}]] and it automatically TeXifies the tick labels on the axes? Alternatively, is there a convenient way to TeXify automatically generated ticks on axes? Many thanks again!

Comment: @TMM For ticks, I would recommend simply using the Latin Modern font instead of MaTeX.  While theoretically it should be possible to auto-process tick labels, there are many obstacle ... Option 1: Use `FullGraphics` to render the axes and ticks as graphics objects, then go from there.  `FullGraphics` has stayed neglected since Mma6 and it's practically unusable in v10.  Option 2: Get the tick labels using `AbsoluteOptions`, then process those.  This works better, but not perfectly.  Often, what AbsoluteOptions returns is quite a bit different from the automatically rendered ticks.

Comment: @TMM Maybe [like this](http://pastebin.com/FF19pKAa).  Note how AbsoluteOptions changes the ticks though ...

Comment: That example doesn't work on my pc (Mma 10.0.1), with errors of the form `Axes::axes: "{{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis specification."` (and similar complaints about Ticks). Something simple like `AbsoluteOptions[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> Automatic], Ticks]` returns the same errors; I guess `AbsoluteOptions` is a bit buggy.

Comment: @TMM Apparently [this is why](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54431/12) (it's a bug), and it's fixed in 10.0.2 ... yes, the main reason why this is difficult is because `AbsoluteOptions` is so unreliable and `FullGraphics` is near useless ...

Comment: Thanks for the link, that indeed seems to be the problem. I upgraded to Mma 10.1 now, and although it works with Ticks, the same idea does not seem to work with "FrameTicks" for which the same bug still seems present.

Comment: I am still not able to get it to work with FrameTicks, and typing in all the ticks for each figure is too much work as I am using this to style tons of different figures used in my thesis. Also specifying ticks manually seems to have the unwanted side-effect of removing the smaller ticks inbetween the larger ticks. For now I'll just keep the ticks the way they were, and use your package for styling the frame labels.

Comment: @TMM I use the CustomTicks package from [here](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) when I need more control over ticks.

Comment: I just figured out how to combine CustomTicks with MaTeX: `MapAt[Function[x, MaTeX[x]], LinTicks[-1, 1], {All, 2}]` will take the tics generated by `LinTicks` and apply `MaTex` to the actually printed labels, i.e., to the second column of the output of `LinTicks`. This even solves the problem of the ugly `1.` being printed instead of `1` or `1.0`.

Comment: @Felix Try this for a speedup: `Transpose@MapAt[MaTeX, Transpose@LinTicks[-1, 1], 2]`.  Applying `MaTeX` to a whole list of expressions will call LaTeX only once.  This works in version 1.6 or later.  Personally I don't often use MaTeX for ticks.  I just set the font to Latin Modern instead.  I use MaTeX only when I have something more complicated than decimal numbers in the ticks, e.g. for $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: MaTeX looks very nice. However, when I try to install it, I get 

In[83]:= Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["C:\Users\iosif\Documents\MaTeX-1.7.3"]

During evaluation of In[83]:= PacletInstall::notavail: No paclet named C:\Users\iosif\Documents\MaTeX-1.7.3 is available for download from any currently enabled paclet sites.

Out[84]= $Failed

How could this be fixed? Thank you.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Try `PacletInstall["C:\Users\iosif\Documents\MaTeX-1.7.3.paclet"]` (not the added extension), and make sure that file actually exists.

Comment: @Szabolcs : Thank you very much for your hint, and sorry for missing the paclet extension. However, now I have a nice looking font for the tick labels with the Times font, but not nearly as nice as in your picture with Latin Modern. The notebook is at the link 
https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ8NnH7Zmwf0OT6s3TJhdhvBzNYByRyJAyWX . Could you please help me with this as well?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Probably this will help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161530/12

Comment: @Szabolcs : Thank you very much again -- for such a great product as MaTeX and your responses. It works great with CMU fonts.

Comment: Can I use that package in mathematica online?

Comment: @Rodrigo Only if you could install a full TeX system in Mathematica Online (i.e. no).

Comment: Note for newbies, to leave math mode, it will look like this: {"\\textrm{Frequency}", "a(z) = \\sin z"}

Comment: @axsvl77 Just use `\text`, not `\textrm`. This is shown in several examples in the documentation. Suggestions on how to improve the documentation are always welcome, but keep in mind that just adding more information  and making it longer is not going to help—people already don't read it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Guilty! I didn't read it once I got it working. Maybe I should say "Note for newbies, read the documentation!"

Comment: Works great! Thank you!